# How can I play a WebRTC livestream from flutter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, webrtc, amazon-kinesis, live-streaming

my use case is a webrtc livestream is coming from AWS Kinesis, that I want to play in flutter app. I am new to WebRTC and AWS. And for **flutter_webrtc** lib, there is no proper documentation available.

Here is my sample response which comes from live video API (hiding few details in response):

```
{
"status": true,
"data": {
    "shadowState": "Device Shadow updated successful!",
    "channelARN": "arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-west-2:",
    "region": "us-west-2",
    "clientId": "clientId",
    "signalingChannelEndpoint": "wss://v-123.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com",
    "signedEndpointUrl": "wss://v-123.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/?...&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host",
    "iceServers": [
        {
            "urls": "stun:stun.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443"
        },
        {
            "urls": [
                "turn:12-34-567-890.t-123.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443?transport=udp",
                "turns:12-34-567-890.t-123.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443?transport=udp",
                "turns:12-34-567-890.t-123.kinesisvideo.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443?transport=tcp"
            ],
            "username": "1....2:djE....UxODc1",
            "credential": "2eg..NOc/1c..."
        }
    ]
}
```

}

And there is no official lib from AWS for this, so I tried to use this lib **aws_kinesis_video_signaling_api** but again no proper documentation is there. Anyone please help me understand these things. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `flutter_webrtc` takes in a configuration map something similar to the one mentioned.

```
Map<String, dynamic> configuration = {
      "iceServers": [
        {"url": "stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
      ]
    };
```

You can add some `offerSdpConstraints` and pass this configuration to

```dart
RTCPeerConnection pc =
        await createPeerConnection(configuration, offerSdpConstraints);
```

to connect to a remote peer. The documentation isn't very helpful but if you're looking for a guide on Flutter x WebRTC, I've written an  [article](https://www.100ms.live/blog/flutter-webrtc) on Flutter and WebRTC integration on the 100ms blog.